# Save an image and get the saved location of image on android emulator

Tags: android, image, save

Actually I have retrieved image saved on facebook but i am not getting how to save image to my emulator and get the path location of saved image as i have to save the path in sqlite.
In most of the answer in stackoverflow,it is only describing about saving the image but not abut retrieving path

```
imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small";
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, fileName+".jpg");
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

And i have even updated my manifest file

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this snippet hope this will solve your issue

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmapimage,
barcodeNumber + ".jpg Card Image", barcodeNumber
+ ".jpg Card Image");
```

Comment: Yep akki ,I think its better to save image like this.But after this how will i retrieve the image location.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shahzadimam: it will return uri in string form you can use that to get there.

Answer (score 1):

your [`file`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object already hold that information.

Get it this way:

```
file.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Yeah,it is right to get location.But now i have changed the method according to Akki. Now how will I get the image location?Thanks Silent............